# My custom ExceptionHandler does not work with Ajax requests

Tags: jsf, exceptionhandler

I don't know why, but my custom ExceptionHandler works great with normal requests, but not with errors in ajax requests.

This is the code of my ExceptionHandler:

```java
public class YourExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourExceptionHandler.class.getName());

    public YourExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        String errorPage = PageUtil.error;
        
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false);
        
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        
        boolean ok = true;
        boolean logged = true;
        boolean loginPage = uri.endsWith("/login.xhtml");
        
        if (! loginPage) {
            if (session == null) {
                logged = false;
            }
            else {
                User user = (User ) session.getAttribute("user");
                
                if (user == null) {
                    logged = false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (logged) {
            Iterable<ExceptionQueuedEvent> queue = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents();
            ExceptionQueuedEvent exceptionEvent;
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext exceptionEventContext;
            Throwable e;
            
            for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> iterator = queue.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                try {
                    exceptionEvent =  iterator.next();
                    exceptionEventContext = exceptionEvent.getContext();
                    e = exceptionEventContext.getException();
                    
                    logger.error("Uncatched exception:\n" + ExceptionUtil.getStackTrace(e));
                    ok = false;
                }
                finally {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            errorPage = "/session_error.jsf";
        }
        
        if (! ok || ! logged) {
            JsfUtil.renderPage(errorPage, context);
        }
        
        this.getWrapped().handle();
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }
}
```

Code of `JsfUtil.renderPage()`:

```java
public static void renderPage(String page, FacesContext context) {
   Application app = context.getApplication();
   ViewHandler viewHandler = app.getViewHandler();
   UIViewRoot root = viewHandler.createView(context, page);
   
   context.setViewRoot(root);
   PartialViewContext partialViewContext = context.getPartialViewContext();
   partialViewContext.setRenderAll(true);
   context.renderResponse();
}
```

JS Console shows me nothing. Http Status code of the request is 200...

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.1

I've done a breakpoint inside the ExceptionHandler and waited the session timeout. Code was executed correctly, it simply not works, despite many answer I see on SO that says the contrary :(

What can I do?

Comment: Console show me no error, and network reports code 200....

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]